# I want to assign unique ids to each image in my html page and submit these values with the form

Tags: jquery

```
$(".available").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('src') == 'available.png') {
        $(this).attr('src', 'selected.png');
        $(this).attr('id', 'selected'+i);
        $(this).attr('name', 'selected'+i);
        $(this).attr('value', 'selected'+i);
        i = i + 1;
    } else {
        $(this).attr('src', 'available.png');
        $(this).attr('id', null);
        $(this).attr('name', null);
    }
});

<input type="text" class="available" /><img src="available.png" class="available"/>
```

I have a hidden field with each image in my page and I want to set the value of hidden field dynamically on clicking upon the image and want to send these value via form submission but I m unable to achieve this.

If I make the type of hidden field to text values are being submitted. Please help how can I set the value of hidden field with image click and submit with form.

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: where you are declaring `i` var?

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: just above the code i m declaring like this, var i=1;

Comment: Add your HTML as well.

Comment: you have given `class="available"` to both `img` and `<input type="text"`. Is that correct. For which element you want to listen for `.click`?

Comment: I want on clicking upon image , the value of text to be set.

Comment: how can i set the value of text box on clicking the image?

Comment: added answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. I have taken text field , you can change those to hidden and put the html markup inside the form.

**Code first**

```
$(function(){
        $(".img-wrapper").on("click", function(){
            $(this).find("img").addClass("selected");
            var index = $(".img-wrapper").index($(this));
            $(this).find("img").attr("id","selected"+index);
            $(this).find("input").val("selected"+index);
        });
    });
```

**Code second**

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="image1.jpg"/>
<input type="text" name="image1"/>
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="image2.jpg"/>
<input type="text" name="image2"/>
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="image3.jpg"/>
<input type="text" name="image3"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case go for this:

Now I have given same class `available` to input hidden and image

**First code**

```
var i =1; 
$("img.available").click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('src') == 'available.png') {
            $(this).attr('src', 'selected.png');
            $(this).attr('id', 'selected'+i);
            $(this).attr('name', 'selected'+i);
            $(this).prev("input.available").val('selected'+i);
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            $(this).attr('src', 'available.png');
            $(this).attr('id', null);
            $(this).attr('name', null);
        }

        $("#valOfHidden").text($(this).prev("input.available").val());

});
```

**Secode Code**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="hidden" class="available" />
 <img src="available.png" class="available"/>

 <p>Value of hidden field:</p>
 <span id="valOfHidden"></span>
```

Comment: this is not working on giving different classes to textbox and image.

Comment: on clicking upon one image it is setting the value of all textboxes. I want the corresponding textbox to be assigned the value.

Comment: In this case also it is doing the same thing

Comment: assuming that your hidden input field is just before the image; above `$.prev()` code should work.

Comment: Glad to know that...:)!